# How to visit all the jar files in a file tree using WalkFileTree

Tags: java

How to visit all the jar files in a file tree using Walk File Tree?

I am trying to get all the xml file names which are local and also in the third party jar. I got all which are present locally but not able to get that are present in jar. Please help.

I have written the code in which i am getting all the xml file name from a csv file , and comparing these xml files with the files present in the system.

```
package com.jmr.profitto.bms;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.file.*;
import java.nio.file.attribute.*;
import static java.nio.file.FileVisitResult.*;
import static java.nio.file.FileVisitOption.*;
import java.util.*;

import javax.annotation.Resource;

import org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.privilegedactions.GetClassLoader;

import com.jmr.profitto.common.util.L2lSystemProperties;
import com.jmr.profitto.common.util.L2lUtil;


public class FindFiles {

    public static class Finder
        extends SimpleFileVisitor<Path> {

        private final PathMatcher matcher;
        public  List<String> fileName = new ArrayList<String>();
        public  Map<String, String> pathName = new HashMap<String, String>();
        public List<String> sectionKeyList;

        Finder(String pattern) {
            matcher = FileSystems.getDefault()
                    .getPathMatcher("glob:" + pattern);
        }


        // Compares the glob pattern against
        // the file or directory name.
        // If the file is present, put it in the form of key value pair
        void find(Path file) {
            Path name = file.getFileName();
            if (name != null && matcher.matches(name)) {
                fileName.add(name.toString());
                pathName.put(name.toString(), file.toFile().getParentFile().getName());
            }
        }

        //check whether the map contains the entered file or not
        boolean containFile(String sectionKey){
            Set<String> keySet = pathName.keySet();
            return keySet.contains(sectionKey);
        }

        //Fetch parent folder of a file.
        String getParent(String sectionKey){
            return pathName.get(sectionKey);
        }

        // Invoke the pattern matching
        // method on each file.
        @Override
        public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file,
                BasicFileAttributes attrs) {
            find(file);
            return CONTINUE;
        }

        // Invoke the pattern matching
        // method on each directory.
        @Override
        public FileVisitResult preVisitDirectory(Path dir,
                BasicFileAttributes attrs) {
            find(dir);
            return CONTINUE;
        }


        //To check the entered file name in the map 
        void showResult(Finder finder, String sectionKey){
         if(!finder.containFile(sectionKey)){
                System.out.println(sectionKey);
            }
       }

       //Read the file created from the db to read the section keys present in it 
       void readSectionKeyForDiffSchema(String fileLocation) throws FileNotFoundException{
            BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileLocation));
            sectionKeyList = new ArrayList<>();
            String line;
            try {
                while((line  = bf.readLine()) != null){
                    // use comma as separator
                    String[] cols = line.split(",");
                    if(cols.length > 5){
                         sectionKeyList.add(cols[5]);
                    }

                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }



    public static void main(String[] args)
        throws IOException {
        //To create the starting directory of traversal 
        Path startingDir = Paths.get(".");

        //Path startingDir = Paths.get("\\UIData\\");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        String fileLocation = sc.next();

        String pattern = "-UIData.xml";

        //Creates the pattern of finding files
        Finder finder = new Finder(pattern);

        //Path startingDir = finder.getFilePath();  

        //To initiate the file walk in file tree
        Files.walkFileTree(startingDir, finder);

        //To read the csv file created for reading the section keys
        finder.readSectionKeyForDiffSchema(fileLocation);

        // To show whether the entered file name is present or not
        for(int i=1 ;i< finder.sectionKeyList.size() ;i++){
            finder.showResult(finder, finder.sectionKeyList.get(i));
        }

    }
}
```

Please find the code here.

Comment: walkFileTree, as its name and javadoc indicates, walks a **file** tree, i.e. visits **files** in directories of your file system. Zip entries of a jar file aren't files on the file system, just like words in a text file aren't files on the file system. If you want to find entries inside jar files, you need to open the jar file and iterate through its entries. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/jar/JarFile.html

Comment: As @JBNizet says, you need to open jar files and look through them. However, if you want to re-use the walkFileTree code you've already written, you can do so, by opening the jar files as separate file systems using the java.nio zip file system provider.